# How can I modify the $submitted variable for a custom node template?

Tags: 7, theming

I have a content type called "Blog post" (machine name = blog_post).

I've set up a custom node template that works properly called "node--blog_post.tpl.php"

I'd like my $submitted output to be "by User Name | Month, Day of Month, Year" (example - "by John Smith | November 2, 2016"

I've been working on this for 2-3 hours without being able to have *any* effect on the output, and have gotten to the point in my searching where the only links I'm finding that seem relevant are things I've already clicked on. I'm stuck.

I know there are multiple ways to do this, but I'm looking for how to make this happen using a theme_preprocess_node function in the template.php file. Not only because I've seen multiple posts saying this is the "best practice", but also to gain more familiarity with the template.php file itself & how it is used.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this.In your theme_preprocess_node function create a new variable which is used in your node--blog_post.tpl.php .

```
 function yourtheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
 $node = $variables['node'];
  if ($node->type == 'blog_post') {
    $created = $node->created;
    $date = date('F j,Y', $created);
    $name = $node->name;
    $variables['new_variable'] = "By ".$name." | ".$date;
  }
}
```

then print this new_variable in your tpl like this.

```
  <div class="content clearfix"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
<?php
  // We hide the comments and links now so that we can render them later.
  hide($content['comments']);
  hide($content['links']);
  print render($content);
  print $new_variable;
?>
```

Output show like this
[image]